# performSave()/doSave() method overriding in eclipse SWT pointers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a customized editor which is extending org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor. Now i need to call  call a function when user clicks on save button. As part of this requirement i have overridden performSave() function and inside that function i called my required function.what i noticed that my function is invoked successfully when the save button invoked.The problem is that even after clicking save button the same button is not getting disabled. As performSave method is not fulfilling my requirement i have tried the same approach with doSave() function. But i stuck with the same issue.As part of this exercise i also have overridden isSaveAllowed() function also.

```
@Override
    public void doSave(IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) {
        super.doSave(progressMonitor);
        userDefinedFunction();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
        return true;
    }

protected void performSave(boolean overwrite,
               IProgressMonitor progressMonitor){ 
    super.performSave(overwrite, progressMonitor);
      userDefinedFunction();
}
```

Please provide leads to call userDefined function on save button click or when user press Ctrl+S command.

Comment: Did you try co reverse order? first call userDefinedFunction then call to super.... ?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are saying the problem is here. Are you save the 'File > Save' menu it is not being disabled once the file has been saved?

Comment: @piradian It seem to be working when i call userDefined function first.

Comment: @greg-449 yeah the save button is not getting being disabled once the file has been saved. Now after changing the invocation as per the piradian i am seeing that save button is getting disabled as expected.

Comment: You don't need to override `#isSaveAsAllowed()` at all. You likely don't need to override `#performSave()` either.

Comment: @nitind: you are right i did only doSave() method and its working perfectly.